# How to set a timeout when reading from a Java RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, linux, file, timeout

I am writing to and reading from a Linux file in java, which in reality is a communication port to a hardware device. To do this I use RandomAccessFile (I'll explain why later) and it works well in most cases. But sometimes a byte is lost and then my routine blocks indefinitely since there is no timeout on the read method.

To give some more details on the file: it is a USB receipt printer that creates a file called /dev/usb/lp0 and though I can use a cups driver to print, I still need the low level communication through this file to query the status of the printer.

The reason I use RandomAccessFile is that I can have the same object for both reading and writing.
I tried to make a version with InputStream and OutputStream instead (since that would allow me to use the available() method to implement my timeout). But when I first open the InputStream and then the OutputStream I get an exception when opening the OutputStream since the file is occupied.

I tried writing with the OutputStream and then closing it before opening the InputStream to read, but then I lose some or all of the reply before it has opened the InputStream.

I tried switching to channels instead (Files.newByteChannel()). This also allows me to have just one object, and the documentation says it only reads the bytes available and returns the count (which also allows me to implement a timeout). But it blocks in the read method anyway when there is nothing to read, despite what the documentation says.

I also tried a number of ways to implement timeouts on the RandomAccessFile using threads.
The first approach was to start a separate thread at the same time as starting to read, and if the timeout elapsed in the thread I closed the file from the thread, hoping that this would unlock the read() operation with an exception, but it didn't (it stayed blocked).
I also tried to do the read in a separate thread and brutally kill it with the deprecated Thread.stop() once the time had elapsed. This worked one time, but it was not possible to reopen the file again after that.

The only solution I have made work is to have a separate thread that continuously calls read, and whenever it gets a byte it puts it in a LinkedBlockingQueue, which I can read from with a timeout. This approach works, but the drawback is that I can never close the file (again for the same reasons explained above, I can't unblock a blocked read). And my application requires that I sometimes close this connection to the hardware.

Anyone who can think of a way to read from a file with timeout that would work in my case (that allows me to have both a read and a write access open to the file at the same time)?

I am using Java8 by the way.

Comment: Have you tried to call `getFilePointer()` and `length()` first to determine if there is a byte available?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. length() returns 0 even if there is data to read. Otherwise it would have been a very nice solution.